# Sum of 3 smallest divisors add to 17

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

How many $3$-digit integers $N$ have the property that the sum of the $3$ smallest divisors of $N$ is equal to $17$?

My approach: We know that $1$ is the smallest divisor of any number.
We then need to find $2$ primes that add to $16$. We find that the triples $(1,3,13), (1,5,11)$ are valid.

To then get the numbers, they must be in the form $39x$ or $55y$, and $x, y$ must be primes greater than $13$ and $11$, respectively.

Doing this gets me the numbers $663, 715, 741, 897, 935$, which gives me $5$ numbers, but the answer is $8$. Where does my solution go astray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where does my solution go astray?

Note that, for $3^113^a$, $a$ can be larger than $1$.

We get
$$3\times 13^2=507,\quad 5^2\times 11=275,\quad 5\times 11^2=605$$

Comment: Wow, for some reason it completely evaded my mind that you can square. Thanks!